I have a problem with this code because it is time invertible symmetric but it is not working
I have this code I want to check for a numerical solution. I get the same shape. The function $y$ is an invertible in time so I plot $y[x]$ and $p[t]$. The $p$ function should decrease but it isn't showing this. Please help me!
Clear["Global`*"]
eqn = {(y''[x]/
  y[x]) + ((3 \[Gamma])/2 - 1) (y'[x]/
  y[x])^2 - ((3 \[Gamma])/2 - 1) (k/y[x]^2) - (3 \[Gamma]*f)/2 == 0};

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqn /. {\[Gamma] -> 1, k -> -1, f -> 0.69}, y[1] == 1,
  y'[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0.01, 2}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{eqn /. {\[Gamma] -> 1, k -> -0.5, f -> 0.69}, 
  y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0.01, 2}];
sol3 = NDSolve[{eqn /. {\[Gamma] -> 1, k -> -0.04, f -> 0.69}, 
  y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0.01, 2}];

(*Analytical solution*)
\[CapitalLambda] = 69/100; \[Gamma] = 1;
sol4 = DSolve[{w''[x]/w[x] + ((3 \[Gamma])/2 - 1) (w'[x]/w[x])^2 - (
  3 \[Gamma]*\[CapitalLambda])/2 == 0, w'[1] == 1, w[1] == 1}, 
  w[x], x] // Simplify;
Print[{"sol1", y[2] /. sol1, y'[2] /. sol1, , "sol2", y[2] /. sol2, y'[2] /. sol2, "sol3", y[2] /. sol3, y'[2] /. sol3}]

Plot[{y[x] /. sol1, y[x] /. sol2, y[x] /. sol3, w[x] /. sol4[[1]]}, {x, 0.01, 2}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"-1", "-0.5", "-0.04", "Analytical Sol"},Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]], FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, "y"})]

eqn1 = {(p''[t]/
  p[t]) + ((3 \[Gamma])/2 - 1) (p'[t]/
  p[t])^2 - ((3 \[Gamma])/2 - 1) (k/p[t]^2) - (3 \[Gamma]*f)/2 == 0};

sol5 = NDSolve[{eqn1 /. {\[Gamma] -> 1, k -> -1, f -> 0.69}, p[-2] == 2.27, p'[-2] == 1.77}, p, {t, -2, -1}];
sol6 = NDSolve[{eqn1 /. {\[Gamma] -> 1, k -> -0.5, f -> 0.69}, p[-2] == 2.35, p'[-2] == 1.91}, p, {t, -2, -1}];
sol7 = NDSolve[{eqn1 /. {\[Gamma] -> 1, k -> -0.04, f -> 0.69}, 
  p[-2] == 2.429, p'[-2] == 2.043}, p, {t, -2, -1}];

Plot[{p[t] /. sol5, p[t] /. sol6, p[t] /. sol7}, {t, -2, -1}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"-1", "-0.5", "-0.04"}, Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]], FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, "p"})]

Print[{"a/sol1", p[-1] /. sol5, "a/sol2", p[-1] /. sol6, "a/sol3",p[-1] /. sol7}]


Although the question is not entirely clear to me, I presume that a solution symmetric about x = 0 is desired.  To produce such a solution, both the ODE and its initial conditions must be symmetric.  So, for example,
sol4 = DSolve[{w''[x]/
    w[x] + ((3  \[Gamma])/2 - 1) (w'[x]/w[x])^2 - (3  \[Gamma]*
    \[CapitalLambda])/2 == 0, w'[1] == 1, w[1] == 1}, w[x], x]
    // Simplify // Flatten

sol5 = DSolve[{w''[x]/
    w[x] + ((3  \[Gamma])/2 - 1) (w'[x]/w[x])^2 - (3  \[Gamma]*
    \[CapitalLambda])/2 == 0, w'[-1] == -1, w[-1] == 1}, w[x], x]
    // Simplify // Flatten

Show[Plot[w[x] /. sol4, {x, -5, 5}], Plot[w[x] /. sol5, {x, -5, 5}]]



The idea is to check the numerical solution is trust-able. that why I want to check backward calculation
